# Why can't we use the '~' operator on a float

Tags: c, operators, bitwise-operators

I recently came across the '~' operator in c. From what I gathered, it simply flips all the bits of a given number and thus, changes it's value. So I played around with it and wrote this code:

> First Program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int x = 100;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    x = ~x;
    printf("signed value = %d\nunsigned value = %u\n", x, x);
    return 0;
}
```

with the output:

```
100
signed value = -101
unsigned value = 4294967195
```

But then, I tried to do the same thing with a float:

> Second Program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    float x = 100;
    printf("%f\n", x);
    x = ~x;
    printf("new value = %f\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

but I get an error:

```
tests.c:6:6: error: wrong type argument to bit-complement
  x = ~x;
```

So I did some research and found out that we are unable to use the '~' operator on floats.
Is this true? If it is, then my question is why?

Comment: But *why* are you trying to flip all the bits of a `float`?

Comment: Bitwise operators like `^`, `&`, `|`, and `^` operate on integers.  Sure, they could be made to operate on the bitwise representation of a floating point number, but the effect on the floating point value would be difficult to describe.  If you really want to do it, you could alias it to an integer and then apply the operator.

Comment: Why? It's a design choice of the language, there's no particular reason why. What result would you expect from a bitwise negation (or any other bitwise operator) on a `float` variable? It surely would not behave the same way it does with integers. It would have little-to-no use.

Comment: @WeatherVane No particular reason. As I mentioned I'm still relatively new to the `~` operator (as well as bitwise operators in general). I asked out of curiosity.

Comment: Curiosity is good! But it needs a purpose, really ;)

Comment: What do you expect from 'double x=21.21; x=~x;'? Think that the C '~' operator acts on the bits in the memory of the variable. Obviously it there might be a float implementation, but not in C.

Comment: Your program's output makes some incorrect assumptions. What it calls "unsigned value" is actually a signed value, of the signed integer type `int` (the value just happens to be positive). Also, bitwise operations are mainly useful on unsigned types.

Answer (score 0):

The uninteresting and unsatisfying answer - because that's how the language is specified:

> **6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators**
> **Constraints**
> 1     The operand of the unary `+` or `-` operator shall have arithmetic type; **of the `~` operator,
> integer type**; of the `!` operator, scalar type.

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

Emphasis mine.

But, *why* was the language specified that way?  Why does it only allow `int` operators for the `~` operator?

Well, several possible reasons.  One, it just isn't that common an operation (at least not in my personal experience) - not many people working with floating point values are terribly interested in bitwise manipulation of those values.  There may be some problem domain where it's used a lot, but I haven't seen it in 30-odd years of programming.  If anyone really needs to do it, they just type-pun or map the float onto an integral type or array of `unsigned char` and do the bit manipulations there, then map back to the original floating point type.

Two, floating-point formats have historically been quite variable - while everyone seems to have converged on IEEE 754 today, back in the '70s and '80s different platforms all did their own thing with floating point.

Three, remember that C compiles to native code - while modern x86 does have native instructions for bitwise manipulation of floating point types, I'm pretty sure that wasn't the case for the hardware around in the early 70s.  There was probably enough of a performance penalty in the generated code that it wasn't worth the effort.